# In IDEA, how to scroll quickly in a file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In `Eclipse`, could scroll up/down across a large file quickly, via `ctrl` + `wheel up` / `wheel down`.

This is convenient sometimes, so is it possible to do this in `IDEA`?

**BTW:**

- Dragging the scrollbars is not desired (it's slow, and not as precise).
- I am not trying to see the file structure, that's another shortcut I already knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option out of the box, but you can install [Fast-scrolling plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling).

Answer (score 2):

I generally hold the "Page Up" or "Page Down" buttons for this.

Comment: LOL, yeah, this is an option, but its granularity is not as good, and need to move hand from mouse to keyboard to do that, so, not as convenient.

Comment: @EricWang how do you press ctrl for `ctrl + wheel up / wheel down`?

Comment: @forpas Usually with left hand on keyboard, and right hand on mouse.

Comment: Agree on the granularity, but I can keep a hand on the mouse just fine while pressing the "Page Down" button (which I believe is @forpas's point).

Comment: @EricWang so I guess ctrl+home or ctrl+end is out of the question.

Comment: @forpas ctrl+home or ctrl+end, just jump to very beginning or very end, what I want is to scroll to some point in the middle, but more quickly, in very large files, like `java.util.Map` source code which has over 1000 lines.

Comment: @RyanC I just tried the plugin `Fast-scrolling plugin` mentioned in the other answer,  it's perfect, worth a try.

Comment: I really don't find myself needing to browse large files this way hardly ever. I generally use the file structure or I'm searching for specific words and advancing through the file using the next/previous arrows for the find.